# form-horizontal not working with bootstrap-sass rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following new.html.erb taken and edited from the Devise gem.

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html:{class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :email%>
<%= f.input :password%>
<%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean%>

<div class = "form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"%>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

but it returns the following instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl4MN.jpg

As displayed in the picture, the form did not take upon the form-horizontal property in bootstrap. The form description is above instead of next to, and somehow the checkbox is all the way to the right.

What did I do wrong? I am following the One Month rails tutorial and it worked when I followed along with the video

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is a problem with ruby gems... when you run bundle install after putting `gem 'simple_form'` into your gem file, it will still install version 3.0.2 instead of the newest version from github (3.1rc).

What you can do is install this within your gemfile instead: `gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form', branch: 'master'`

Then run bundle install. It should update your gem to the correct version (3.1rc). Then, run `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` again. Every time it stops with a conflict, type 'y' and then  hit enter to overwrite those old initializer files causing the conflict. Terminate the rails server, and then turn it back on. You should be good to go and see the working bootstrap simple-forms if your code is correct.

For example:

```
'<%= simple_form_for(@story, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>`
```

Comment: This QA could be applied to many cases of <bootstrap thing> not working in Rails. I´ve found out the hard way you have to check if the classes are being properly rendered when using Rails tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is lacking a lot of `classes` in order to properly display.

[Bootstrap Form-Horizontal Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true %>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> 
                <%= f.label :remember_me %>
            </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
</div>
```